# Script not working (but works fine on other site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok this is probably a dumb question but, I'll ask. I'm trying to make a div stick when you pass a point on the page while scrolling. I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       var s = $("#sticker");
       var pos = s.position();                    
         $(window).scroll(function() {
       var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (windowpos >= pos.top + 335) {
           s.addClass("stick");
      } else {
          s.removeClass("stick"); 
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Which works fine on one of my site. But now I'm trying it on a new site. And every time I get an error in my console log saying: `TypeError: $ is not a function` And when I look at the error in my code it highlights the `$(document).ready(function() {` part.

If I remove the `$(document).ready` part and the `});` it tells me the `var s = $("#sticker");` part is `$ is not a function`.

I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       var s = $("#sticker");
       var pos = s.position();                    
         $(window).scroll(function() {
       var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (windowpos >= pos.top + 335) {
           s.addClass("stick");
      } else {
          s.removeClass("stick"); 
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Then it skips the `(document).ready` part, but it again tells me my `var` part is not a function.

If I remove the script I don't have any console log messages. What could be the problem? I tried putting the code in the `header` and `footer` and even just before the `<div id="sticker">...</div>`. Nothing seems to work. The script works perfectly on an other site...

Comment: Try it this way: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` (*note the `$`*) Sounds a bit like `noConflict` mode.

Comment: May be obvious but you do have JQuery included and available on your page?

Comment: @ste2425, Yes I am. All other jQuery codes work fine, on the same page work fine...

Comment: @eisbehr, Ok that worked. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running jQuery in `noConfilct` mode. Which mean, jQuery is only available by `jQuery`, not over `$`. You can wrap your code with an `ready state` or an `IIFE` to get access to jQuery by `$`.

**Ready State:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // access jQuery by '$' inside
});

// this is a shorthand for the above '.ready' creation
jQuery(function($) {
    // access jQuery by '$' inside
});
```

**IIFE:**

```
(function($) {
    // access jQuery by '$' inside
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. Why haven't I ever had this same problem on any other of my sites? Could it be this piece of code?

`//Making jQuery Google API
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js', false, '2.2.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');`

Comment: In general the `noConflict` mode is just stared with `jQuery.noConflict();`. I don't know how the `wp_register_script` function is working, but it could be. If you want to register jQuery again to the `$`, you can just do something like `window.$ = jQuery;`, but keep in mind, there meight be other scripts using the `$` and you can become other problems then. If something has put jQuery in `noConflict` mode, or reassign the `$`, there would be a reason for it ...

Comment: Well I'll leave it as is now. I don't want to mess up the other scripts. Thanks again.